# How do you calculate confidence interval from effect size, p-value, and t-value only?

Tags: confidence-interval, interaction

I am using an online calculator to calculate simple slopes for a moderation plot. I need to calculate the confidence interval around the simple slope, but the calculator only provides the following:

Simple slope: -.20
t-value of simple slope: -1.826
p-value: 0.070

Is there a way to calculate confidence intervals for the simple slope using only this information? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the standard error of the estimated slope. The $t$ statistic is computed as

$$t = \frac{\hat{\beta}}{\hat{\sigma}}$$

where $t$ and $\hat{\beta}$ are the t-value and slope estimate you have. Rearranging we can estimate the unknown $\hat{\sigma}$

$$\hat{\sigma} = \frac{\hat{\beta}}{t}$$

For your values this is

$$0.1095 = \frac{-0.2}{-1.826}$$

A confidence interval would normally be produced using a critical value $T$ from the $t$ distribution

$$\text{CI} = \hat{\beta} \pm (T \times \hat{\sigma})$$

This requires the residual degrees of freedom of the model. This would be equal to the number of observations - 2 (one for the intercept and one for the slope).

For example, the critical values for a 95% confidence interval assuming 10, 50, 100 residual degrees of freedom are

```
> qt(0.975, c(10, 50, 100))
[1] 2.228139 2.008559 1.983972
```

(Note that I evaluate the 0.975 probability quantile as half (2.5% of the 1 - 0.95 interval) is in the upper tail of the $t$ distribution, and half in the lower tail. As were are adding *and* subtracting this critical value we only want the upper tail value.)

If you don't have a convenient way of evaluating the quantiles of the $t$ distribution, and assuming you have more than 20-25 observations, you could just use the critical value of 2 which is going to be almost indistinguishable from the correct value for a 95% confidence interval.

Taking this approach we have

$$\text{CI} = -0.2 \pm (2 \times 0.1095)$$

which yields an interval of $-0.419 \text{ -- } 0.019$. This interval contains zero, which is consistent with the $p$ values being greater than 0.05.

Comment: Thanks, that was a very clear explanation and a huge help.