# Can anyone work out the P value from this graph?

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value

[image]

Can anyone work out the p value just based on the graph below? I cannot understand how this is calculated and what additional information I would needs to work it out.

Comment: I can't find directly a good link but this seems like a duplicate. One example is https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/338661/computing-a-p-value-from-95-confidence-interval

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/416091/

Comment: The other direction https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/300668/

Comment: It looks like the picture provides a confidence interval. Why would one need a p-value then?

Answer (score 4):

I read this graph as showing two groups of observations, with a difference in means of -19.5, and a confidence interval for this difference of (-26.0, -12.5). It is slightly asymmetric, but it extends on average by 6.75 out from the mean.

We don't know the confidence *level* of this interval, but if no information is given, then it is almost certainly 95%.

We can use the standard formula for the CI of the mean to work out the standard error of the mean used:

$$ \text{CI} = m \pm z_{0.975}\times\text{SEM} = m \pm 1.96\times\text{SEM}, $$

so

$$\text{SEM} \approx\frac{6.75}{1.96}\approx 3.44.$$

We get a p value for a one sided test against the null hypothesis of $\mu=0$ (which I assume you are interested in) in R like this:

```
> 1-pnorm(0,-19.5,3.44)
[1] 7.198256e-09
```

Given the assumptions above, and the rounding that went into the graphic, I would report $p<.0001$, and nothing more precise.

Comment: @PBulls: yes, you are right, I edited... I'm not good with numbers...

Comment: Being asymmetric it probably relates to ratios or log values instead of a linear scale. And aside from that it is not very ge real to assume that the confidence interval is based on a z-test or standard error.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help and fantastic contributions!

Answer (score 4):

You can *approximate* the *P*-value from a confidence interval, which I'm assuming is what is shown over the bars at 95%. If the two-sided $1-\alpha$ interval is $(\text{L}, \text{U})$ then you can first approximate the standard error of the mean using the (inverse) standard normal cumulative density $\Phi$ like so:

$$\text{SE}=\frac{|\text{U}-\text{L}|}{2\cdot\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha/2)}\approx 3.444
$$

Then, you can convert this into a Z- or t-statistic using the observed difference ($\Delta=-19.5$) and use that to calculate a (two-sided) *P*-value:

$$
P=2\cdot\big(1-\Phi(|\Delta/\text{SE}|)\big)\approx 1.5\times10^{-8}
$$

The value being this small will make the approximation have a pretty large relative error (also because we didn't have many decimals to begin with), so keep that in mind when you want to compare this against very stringent cut-offs (e.g. $\ll0.001$).

[Here](https://www.bmj.com/content/343/bmj.d2304)'s a reference with some more details on such calculations.

In R the following code will get you these results:

```r
delta <- -19.5
se <- abs(-12.5 - -26) / (2 * qnorm(.975))
#> 3.443941

pval <- 2 * pnorm(abs(delta / se), lower.tail = FALSE)
#> 1.495158e-08
```